# Not able to view custom data added (used Schema Extension) for a user

Tags: azure-active-directory

In the Azure AD, I have created a Native application and assigned users to it. I want to create an extension property using Microsoft Graph's SchemaExtension. I have written the code for the same and it does not throw any errors and the extension is also added(able to see the Id) through code. I then add the value of the custom property for a user under the application but am not able to view in the Azure portal or in the code when I do the below:

I have supplied the value for the custom property after updating the status of the schema extensions to "Available" but still not able to fetch the custom property value in code or in the UI. Please provide inputs if any.

Below is the code i am using:

```
var aap = new AzureAuthenticationProvider();
                var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(aap);
                IEnumerable<string> targetType = new string[] { "User" };
                SchemaExtension extensionDefinition = new SchemaExtension
                {
                    ODataType = "microsoft.graph.ComplexExtensionValue",
                    Id = $"crmCompanyId",
                    Description = "This extension is for company id",
                    Owner = "fac4cdd3-1015-4ed5-8a7b-6008095750e6",
                    Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>()
                    {
                        new ExtensionSchemaProperty() { Name = "cid", Type = "String" }
                    },
                    Status = "InDevelopment",
                    TargetTypes = targetType
                };
                SchemaExtension schemaExtension = //code to add extensionDefinition    
                var updateSchemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
                {
                    Status = "Available"
                };
                //update schema to available status
                var updatedSchema = code to update extension
                IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                extensionInstance.Add(schemaExtension.Id, new
                MyDBExtensionClass("testMyExtension"));
                User updateUser = new User()
                {
                    AdditionalData = extensionInstance
                };

                var updatedUser = await graphserviceClient.Users["9ca2bb42-a7f8-487c- 
                87a0 - 38513057886d"].Request().UpdateAsync(updateUser);//AzureADGraphUser3 
                - 9ca2bb42 - a7f8 - 487c - 87a0 - 38513057886d
                await Task.Delay(10000);
```

Could you please review the code and let me know what I am missing...I have referred the comments at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/151 `enter code here`by Michael Maier. Let me know in case I need to provide any further info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to view the property i had set once i found this link:https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/238

I queried the extension property on a user this way and was able to view the property value i set.